# Codeigniter how to get userid after login

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, registration, userid

I have successfully created a registration and login system.
I have used useremail and password in the login form and I want to display the username and other properties related to that logged in user.

What are the simplest and best practices to get the userid after a login in codeigniter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As good coder create `session` at login time and use `session` at website wide.

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    $user = $this->db
        ->select("username, name, phone")
        ->where(
             [
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => md5($password)
             ]
         )
        ->get("table_name")
        ->row();

   if ($user) {
         $logindata = [
             'userid' => $user->username,
             'name'   => $user->name,
             'phone'  => $user->phone
         ];
         $this->session
              ->set_userdata($logindata);
         return true;
   }
   else {
         return false;
   }
}
```

Then after you can use anywhere in website

```
echo $this->session->userid;
```

I hope it will help you in general way.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice would be that when you check the login details in your model after success you should create a session saving userid of that user and use that anywhere in your application for fetching respective data against that user. Take a look at following psuedo code for login user.

```
    public function userAuthentication($username,$pass)
{

$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('password',md5($pass));
$result = $this->db->get('users')->result();

if(!empty($result)){
   $this->session->set_userdata('userlogged_in', $result[0]->id);
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}

}
```

You can place this function in your model and apply it in your controller. I hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome, i am glad that i was able to help :) .

Answer (score 0):

You may create a session and set user id after successful login.